# GPT disk looks different in external docking bay and internal swap bay

Tags: fdisk, gpt, parted

I have a hard disk that I use for backups via a USB 2.0 docking station. The disk has a GPT and one single ext4 partition. Everything is fine via the docking station, but if I attach the disk to an internal SATA port, or put it in a swap bay in my PC, the GPT is not there any more.

Here's what I get when the disk is in the docking bay, an everything works:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdg
Disk /dev/sdg: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 488378646 sectors
Disk model: 001-1CH164
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2C0A0696-2318-4BBD-9329-0115AB5AC313
Device     Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdg1    512 488378367 488377856  1.8T Linux filesystem

$ sudo parted /dev/sdg print
Model: ST2000DM 001-1CH164 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdg: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name      Flags
1      2097kB  2000GB  2000GB  ext4         MUSICBUP
```

Here's the output of the same commands when the disk is in the internal swap bay, or any other internal SATA port:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdg
GPT PMBR size mismatch (488378645 != 3907029167) will be corrected by write.
Disk /dev/sdg: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: ST2000DM001-1CH1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdg1           1 3907029167 3907029167  1.8T ee GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

$ sudo parted /dev/sdg print
Error: /dev/sdg: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA ST2000DM001-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdg: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

Versions: `fdisk from util-linux 2.33.1`, and `parted (GNU parted) 3.2`

OS: Debian 10 Buster `4.19.0-14-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.171-2 (2021-01-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`smartctl` info (same in both cases):

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST2000DM001-1CH164
Serial Number:    Z1E6Q80D
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 065bb1ceb
Firmware Version: CC27
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Mar 28 13:00:17 2021 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

**What I tried already**: moving the partition to the right, with `gparted`, in order to make sure that it is aligned to MiB. That did not help, and actually `parted` was already telling me that the partition was optimally aligned (when in docking).

One thing I noticed is that logical sector size differs when in the external docking (4096) and internally (512).

Of course I copied the data elsewhere and I could just reformat it while it's attached to the PC, but I'd like to learn a bit from this and see if there's a way to correct the current GPT. Any ideas?

Comment: "Correcting the current GPT" is only a small part of the problem. If the existing filesystems actually use the larger sector size, it means all the filesystem metadata would need to be updated too, with every 4096-byte block represented as 8 512-byte blocks. This would cause the filesystem metadata to take up more space than before, which would require further reorganization... it is not a trivial task. I'd recommend following frostschutz's answer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, GPT still depends on the logical sector size, and in your case it differs:

> ```
> Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
> ```

vs.

> ```
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
> ```

The difference usually happens because some controllers / USB bridges emulate the wrong sector size.

You can work around it by using `losetup` with `--sector-size` parameter:

```
losetup --find --show --partscan --sector-size 4096 /dev/sdg
```

Then check for `/dev/loopXpY` devices.

If you get another USB enclosure that does not force 4K logical sector size, you'll have to re-create the partition table for 512 byte sectors. It's not possible to create one partition table that works for both sector sizes - you could do it with LVM but LVM is not a partition table format.